# Passing the second variable to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm having trouble passing the second variable to LocalStorage.

On the first page I have 2 divs, after clicking on each of them, I would like to pass various variables:

```
 $(".questionAnswerItem8447").click(function (val) {
    localStorage.setItem('kasaVisible', val);
 });

$(".questionAnswerItem8448").click(function (va2) {
    localStorage.setItem('autaVisible', va2);
});
```

Then, on the second page, I would like to refer to these variables.

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('kasaVisible')) {
    kasaNagrody.classList.add('activeContainer');
    autaNagrody.classList.add('noActiveContainer');
     console.log('kasa works');

} else if (localStorage.getItem('autaVisible')) {
    kasaNagrody.classList.add('noActiveContainer');
    autaNagrody.classList.add('activeContainer');
    console.log('auto works');
}
```

Unfortunately, regardless of which div I click on the first page, the second always displays the message from the first if

```
console.log('kasa works');
```

As if he didn't see it at all:

```
 localStorage.setItem('autaVisible', va2);
```

Why?

Comment: What value are you trying to store?  Storage can only store strings.  All values will thusly be true, if they exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the code in an `if else` statement.

So if you have clicked the first div at some point, then you have set the value for the first div in local storage. Therefore it will hit the if statement and `localStorage.getItem('kasaVisible')` will be true. The code in the if block will run and your code will never hit the `else if` block.

Try using 2 if statements instead:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('kasaVisible')) {
    kasaNagrody.classList.add('activeContainer');
    autaNagrody.classList.add('noActiveContainer');
     console.log('kasa works');

}
if (localStorage.getItem('autaVisible')) {
    kasaNagrody.classList.add('noActiveContainer');
    autaNagrody.classList.add('activeContainer');
    console.log('auto works');
}
```

Alternatively you can look at clearing out the first value with `localStorage.removeItem(item)`  if the second div has been clicked (if this is the behaviour you want).

Note: You can view your localStorage in chrome dev tools. Open devtools > application > storage > Local Storage

Comment: The "alternative" isn't an alternative.  It would be the approach to take.  The two ifs will cause the second case to always be true, if both options are clicked, regardless of order.  Though this answer doesn't take into consideration what value the OP is actually storing.  If they are trying to store true/false. their logic could potentially change to be `=== 'true'`.  But we have to wait for more feedback before being able to answer that way.

Comment: Thank you, adding "localStorage.removeItem(item)"  helped